# Problem implementing toy code from tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm working through the tutorials in [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential) and I've come across one which gives me an error, and I can't see where I'm going wrong:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(precision = 3, suppress = True)
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing

# Import some data
abalone_train = pd.read_csv(
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/abalone_train.csv", header=None, 
    names=["Length", "Diameter", "Height", "Whole weight", "Shucked weight",
           "Viscera weight", "Shell weight", "Age"])

# separate the features and labels for training
abalone_features = abalone_train.copy()
abalone_labels = abalone_features.pop('Age')

# pack the features into a single NumPy array
abalone_features = np.array(abalone_features)

# make a regression model predict Age
abalone_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Dense(64),
  layers.Dense(1)
])

abalone_model.compile(loss = tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                      optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam())

# train the model by passing features and labels to Model.fit
abalone_model.fit(x = abalone_features, y = abalone_labels, epochs = 10)
```

This is pretty much straight from the tutorial, but I get an error when fitting the model:

```
ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays. You passed: target=0        7
1        6
2       14
3       16
4       13
        ..
3315    15
3316    10
3317    11
3318    16
3319    19
Name: Age, Length: 3320, dtype: int64
```

I understand from [here](https://groups.google.com/g/keras-users/c/d0nnsr0RTuY) that the input needs to be 2 `np.array`s, but inspecting `abalone_features` shows:

```
abalone_features
Out[31]: 
array([[0.435, 0.335, 0.11 , ..., 0.136, 0.077, 0.097],
       [0.585, 0.45 , 0.125, ..., 0.354, 0.207, 0.225],
       [0.655, 0.51 , 0.16 , ..., 0.396, 0.282, 0.37 ],
       ...,
       [0.53 , 0.42 , 0.13 , ..., 0.374, 0.167, 0.249],
       [0.395, 0.315, 0.105, ..., 0.118, 0.091, 0.119],
       [0.45 , 0.355, 0.12 , ..., 0.115, 0.067, 0.16 ]])
```

I'm not sure where I'm (or the tutorial is?) wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is not your `abalone_features` but your `abalone_labels`. They are still a Pandas series:

```
>>> type(abalone_labels)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

You need to change them into an array, just as you did with features:

```
abalone_model.fit(x = abalone_features, y = np.asarray(abalone_labels), epochs = 10)
```

Or, more close to what you did with the features:

```
abalone_labels = np.array(abalone_labels)
```

(Personally, I don't like reassignments like this, precisely because they can cause confusion about types.)